# Concurrence through a triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Suppose that points A, B, C form a triangle and that A' $\in$ $l_{BC}$ and B' $\in$ $l_{AC}$ and C' $\in$ $l_{AB}$ are such that the lines $l_{AA'}$, $l_{BB'}$, $l_{CC'}$ are concurrent at G.

Compute: $\frac{A-G}{A-A'}+\frac{B-G}{B-B'}+\frac{C-G}{C-C'}$

I tried expanding the fractions by multiplying by $(A-A')(B-B')(C-C')$ but that gave me a terribly large expression.

I know that if they are concurrent with A', B', C' being the midpoints on the opposite sides, then G will be 2/3 of the distance from A to A', so then I would expect $\frac{A-G}{A-A'}=\frac{\frac{2L}{3}}{\frac{3L}{3}}$ where L is the length from A to A' and the total expression summing to 2.  Is this correct? 
And is this the only option for them all to be concurrent.

Comment: `I know that if they are concurrent with A', B', C' being the midpoints on the opposite sides, then ... total expression summing to 2.` Correct. `is this the only option for them all to be concurrent` No. Choose any point $G$ inside the triangle, and let $A', B', C'$ be the intersection points with the opposite sides. Then obviously $AA', BB', CC'$ are concurrent at $G$, by construction. See also [Ceva's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceva%27s_theorem).

Comment: This value is always $2$ if the intersection is inside the triangle. This is a very interesting fact. I really like to see a proof of this.